# can i manually change doc path of swagger?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger-2.0

I want my manual path of swagger.
The UI path of swagger has been changed with this properties

springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/v1/swagger-ui.html

but I also want to change swagger doc url path

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiPFb.png) -> click here for image

I want to change my url which is /v3/api-docs/public to /test/v3/api-docs/public

POM dependency are

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Got the solution to the base URL before
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/api/v1/swagger-ui.html
springdoc.api-docs.path = /api/v1/v3/api-docs

if base URL before both are not same then it will not work

Answer (score 1):

To change the Swagger API documentation URL path, you can use the following property:

```
springdoc.api-docs.path=/test/v3/api-docs/public
```

So, in your application.properties or application.yml, you should have something like:

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/v1/swagger-ui.html
springdoc.api-docs.path=/test/v3/api-docs/public
```

Comment: I have added a filter to my service.
So, after adding above config.
code breaks here       chain.doFilter(request, response);

Comment: Change the code in the security class so that the endpoints specified in .yml do not require authorization